# How can the jerk tend towards infinity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, singularities, jerk

Consider a block of mass $m$ kept on a rough surface. A time varying force $F =t$ is applied on the block in a direction parallel to the surface. Assuming the coefficient of static and kinetic friction to be $\mu_s$ and $\mu_k$ respectively, we can make the following cases:

1. $0≤t≤\mu_sN$:
   $$a_{block} = 0$$
2. $t > \mu_sN$:
   $a_{block}$ increases linearly from $(\mu_s-\mu_k)\frac{N}{m}$

If we calculate the average jerk from time $t = \mu_sN -\delta t$ to $t = \mu_sN +\delta t$ using $$j = \frac{∆a}{∆t}$$ we get $$j = \frac{(\mu_s-\mu_k)N}{m×2(\delta t)}$$ So as $\delta t \rightarrow  0$, $j \rightarrow \infty$. Is this situation really valid in real life? How is it possible to have such changes in acceleration in just no time?

**Update**

$F = m\int_{\mu_sN -\delta t}^{\mu_sN +\delta t} jdt$ so if jerk tends to infinity will the force not tend to infinity? Is it possible to have infinite force acting on a body?

Comment: Are you saying there is a maximum force something can experience? F=ma. Disregarding relativity what else is acceleration dosed to do. In relativity the situation is slightly more complicated but force is still not limited

Comment: This is just a product of the unphysical idealization that the friction force is an discontinuous function of the velocity.  In a more realistic model, the coefficient of friction will decrease from $\mu_{s}$ to $\mu_{k}$ as the speed increases from $v_{0}=0$ to some small $v_{1}$.

Comment: @Buzz But does that really happen? We were taught that from the time the object just starts to move $f_k = \mu_kN$ acts on the object.

Comment: Yes, it does happen.  That's why I called the discontinuity an "unphysical idealization."  There is actually a lot of interesting and complicated physics in how the coefficient of friction $\mu$ evolves at low speeds.

Comment: Why should jerk be finite?

Comment: Large jerks are common. Think of firing a bullet.

Comment: @Buzz please explain the physics behind evolution of $\mu$.

Comment: The Coulomb friction coefficient $\mu$ is just a mathematical fiction (and perfectly rigid bodies are also fictional). There is no physics that can "explain" it because it isn't real. More realistic models of friction have relative "pre-sliding" motion of the components for any applied force level down to zero.  See https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/34469614.pdf for eaxmple.